# Why does my scroll function trigger on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to create a simple scroll effect where the page header hides when the page scrolls down and reappears on scroll up. The `HTML`:

```
<header class="siteHeader">...</header>
```

...is hidden by applying the `CSS` class "siteHeader--up."

I'm using `jQuery`. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

    var $siteHeader = $('.siteHeader');
    var $window = $(window);

    // to determine scroll direction. initializes to 0 on page load
    var scrollReference = 0;  

    function fixedHeader () {

        var scrollPosition = $window.scrollTop();

        // if page is scrolling down, apply the CSS class
        if (scrollPosition > scrollReference) 
        {
            $siteHeader.addClass('siteHeader--up');
        } 

        // otherwise, page is scrolling up. Remove the class
        else 
        {
            $siteHeader.removeClass('siteHeader--up');
        }

        // update reference point to equal where user stopped scrolling
        scrollReference = scrollPosition
    }

    $window.scroll(function () {
        fixedHeader();
    });

});
```

This works fine for the most part. The problem is when I scroll down the page and then refresh the page. Somehow the scroll function is being triggered. The header will be visible for a moment and then hide (as though the page thinks it's being scrolled down). The function is being triggered on page load (confirmed with a `console.log`), but I don't understand why, because it's only supposed to fire on scroll.

Can someone help me understand what's going on and how I can prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, You can try make it display: none by default, and than check page position, if is enough to top .show() if no do nothing

Comment: The browser remembers the scroll state when you refresh the page and will automatically scroll down to the place you were when you refreshed.  That's why the scroll event fires when you reload the page.

Comment: That makes sense, HaukurHaf. So, can you think of a way to prevent this function from firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. When the page is refreshed, the browser remembers the scroll position and it scrolls the page to that position, later on the scroll event is fired.

I think that this could be a workaround to solve your problem:

When the `jQuery` scroll event is fired you can get the `timeStamp` property and if this `timeStamp` is very close to the `window.onload` `timeStamp`, surely it can't be an event triggered by the user:

> I've used a value of 50 milliseconds, test if it is sufficient, I think that it is.

```
var startTime = false;

$(function () {

    var $siteHeader = $('.siteHeader');

    var $window = $(window);

    // to determine scroll direction. initializes to 0 on page load
    var scrollReference = 0;  

    function fixedHeader () {

        var scrollPosition = $window.scrollTop();

        // if page is scrolling down, apply the CSS class
        if (scrollPosition > scrollReference) 
        {
            $siteHeader.addClass('siteHeader--up');
        } 

        // otherwise, page is scrolling up. Remove the class
        else 
        {
            $siteHeader.removeClass('siteHeader--up');
        }

        // update reference point to equal where user stopped scrolling
        scrollReference = scrollPosition
    }

    $window.on("load", function (evt) {

        startTime = evt.timeStamp;

    });

    $window.on("scroll", function (evt) {

        if(!startTime || evt.timeStamp - startTime < 50) return;

        fixedHeader();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Loading the function on window load as well as in the scroll function:

```
 $window.load(function(){
     fixedHeader();
 });
```

---

Or on document ready maybe:

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fixedHeader();
});
```

---

This should trigger and reset the values in the Variables you made and therefore determine whether to set the header to fixed or not, regardless of the scroll position.

Let me know if it works because i'm kinda curious too :)

Comment: The events are fired in this order: document ready > window onload > automatic scroll event.